# Scraping temporary web queries in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've been working on an R script that would automatically scrape the text from the Congressional Record hosted at THOMAS (thomas.loc.gov).

THOMAS allows users to 'browse' through the daily issues of the Congressional Record. I think the way that it will work best is to follow these steps:

1. List out the links to each daily issue (ex.: http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/B?r101:@FIELD(FLD003+h)+@FIELD(DDATE+19901019 is the link for the 10/19/1990 issue in the House)
2. For each link, get all of the links to the individual 'articles' (the articles are linked to with a temporary search query that is only active for 30 minutes).
3. Loop through the articles and follow the link for the 'printer-friendly' version (for a variety of reasons, this seems like the best option -- for example, if you look at the 10/19/1990 House issue linked above and click on article 37--"CONFERENCE REPORT ON H.R. 5229, DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION AND RELATED AGENCIES APPROPRIATIONS ACT, 1991"--you will be directed to a new page with a list of links to sections of the debate over HR 5229. The 'printer-friendly' version lists out all the text in one place.
4. Scrape the text from the printer-friendly page

I'm getting hung up on step 3. For some reason, it always returns a '404 Not Found' error.

The following code gets most of the way there:

```
setwd("U:/Congressional Record")
require(XML)

root <- "http://thomas.loc.gov/"
url <- "http://thomas.loc.gov/home/Browse.php?&n=Issues&c=101"
```

^^points to the links for the 101st Congress

```
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- as.vector(xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href"))
hou <- grep("\\+h\\)", links)
sen <- grep("\\+s\\)", links)

links <- sort(c(links[hou], links[sen]))
link.ex <- 'href=\\"[^]].*<em>'
title.ex <- '[0-9]+\\s+\\.\\s+\\w*' 
timeout <- 'Search results in THOMAS are temporary and are deleted 30 minutes after creation.Please try your search again.'
```

^^gets the links from the page and sets up the required regular expressions for use below.

```
txt <- NULL ##container for scraped text
for (j in links) { ##begin loop through issues
    ##append a break for each day
    txt <- c(txt, '*#*#start new day#*#*', j)
    u <- paste(root, j, sep="")
    doc <- htmlParse(u)
    ##pull out the links
    l <- as.vector(xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href"))
    ##find subset only the links that lead to text from CR
    s <- grep("query", l)

    ##get a list of titles for each entry
    t <- readLines(u)
    ##clean it up a little
    t <- gsub('</*\\w*/*>', '', t, perl=TRUE)
    ##find the titles
    tInds <- grep(title.ex, t)
    tEnds <- regexpr('<', t[tInds])
    titles <- substr(t[tInds], 1, tEnds-2)

    for (k in 1:length(s)) { ##begin loop through articles of the daily issue
        u <- paste(root, l[s[k]], sep='')
        t <- readLines(u)
        doc2 <- htmlParse(u)
        as.vector(xpathSApply(doc2, "//a/@href"))
        ##refresh the search if it has taken too long
        timed <- grep(timeout, t)
        if (length(timed)>0) {
            u <- paste(root, j, sep="")
            doc <- htmlParse(u)
            ##pull out the links
            l <- as.vector(xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href"))   
            u <- paste(root, l[k], sep='')
            t <- readLines(u)
        }

        ##find the 'printer friendly' link
        ##for some reason the printer link doesn't work when I try to
        ##automatically scrape it from the site...

        i <- grep('Printer Friendly Display', t)
        ##extract the link and follow it
        pr <- regexpr(link.ex, t[i], perl=TRUE)
        li <- paste(root, 
            substr(t[i], pr[1]+8, pr[1]+attr(pr, 'match.length')[1]-7),
            sep='')
        t <- readLines(li)

        ##clean the text
        t <- gsub('</*\\w*/*>', '', t, perl=TRUE)

        ##code to scrape the text...

    } ##end loop through articles

} ##end loop through issues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
li <- paste(root, 
            substr(t[i], pr[1]+8, pr[1]+attr(pr, 'match.length')[1]-7),
            sep='')
```

It is giving you, for example:

```
> li
[1] "http://thomas.loc.gov/gi-bin/query/C?r101:./temp/~r101PhW9pi"
```

When you want (with "cgi-bin" instead of "gi-bin"):

```
"http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/C?r101:./temp/~r101PhW9pi"
```

Some other comments about your code:

1. `txt <- c(txt, '*#*#start new day#*#*', j)` is a very inefficient
   way of growing a vector.
2. `doc <- htmlParse(u)` and `t <-
   readLines(u)` are nearly redundant (you do this once in your
   outer loop and once in your inner loop). You could `readLines` then `parseHTML` on the retrieved object to halve your server requests.
3. This line
   `as.vector(xpathSApply(doc2, "//a/@href"))` doesn't store anything.
4. You reuse a lot of variable names, like `t` and `u`, to mean different things at different points in time, which is confusing and will inevitably cause you problems at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Those are really helpful (I can't believe I didn't catch that silly mistake).

Comment: No problem; happens to all of us. If you found this helpful, I'd appreciate an upvote and/or accept of the answer.